# Сериализация нескольких объектов в один xml файл

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброе время суток, Уважаемый ХэшКод!

Реализовал сериализацию объектов (конфигурационные объекты программы) в xml файлы посредством XmlSerialiser. Все отличненько, но очень неудобно сохранять каждый объект в отдельный файл, т.к. сериализатор формирует документ с нуля.

Можно ли как-то это обойти и научить сериализатор сохранять в стрим не с нуля, а дописывать в него данные и соответственно потом все это дело десериализовать?..

На ум приходит только создать XMl Документ, и в него самому записывать фрагменты из сериализованного стрима. Потом также все производить в обратном порядке.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

**UPDATE**

Мой "Проект" состоит из нескольких проектов, а именно:

- Модуль по работе с базами данныех firebird (скачанный с официального сайта и не собирается, линкуется статически)
- Модуль Library.dll, в нем собраны общие классы носящие выполняющие основную логику программы и систему логирования работы приложения. Линкуется также статически.
- Исполнительный модуль, являющийся главным окном программы (Вот у него есть первый вариант конфигурации, о нем соответственно я знаю все, хоть и он является частью интерфейса конфигурации)
- Модуль по реализации системы плагинов, он линкуется статически к исполнительному модулю, чтобы он мог взаимодействовать с системой плагинов. Именно в этом модуле описано все необходимое поведение системы плагинов, интерфейсы и базовые классы плагинов. В нем также описаны классы и интерфейсы конфигурации плагинов.
- Модуль плагина, отвечающий за проверку баз данных.
- Модуль плагина, отвечающий за проверку базы данных в истории изменений.
- Модуль плагина, отвечающий за просмотр базы данных и выполнению в них запросов.
- Модуль плагина ... и так далее.

Так вот, часть плагинов поддерживает возможность сохранения своих настроек (не все). В момент старта программы, она проверяет наличие длл в определенном каталоге и инициализирует плагины, и если плагин поддерживает интерфейс конфигурации - она ему говорит, что необходимо ее загрузить.

По завершение программы, она также бежит по списку плагинов и просит их сохранить эту конфигурацию.

Собственно на момент загрузки и сохранения, исполнительный модуль может оперировать каким-то образом с этими плагинами и говорить куда им что сохранять. Вот тут и хотелось бы, чтобы результирующий файл был один, а не по количеству плагинов.

Comment: Неужели Вы так часто сериализуете/десериализуете? При старте десериализовали конфиг, при изменении настроек и при выходе сериализовали и в файлик сохранили, нет? Если так то не стоит заморачиваться с дописыванием в файл ИМХО

Comment: @donil, Само собой, не часто, только при старте и закрытии программы. Просто файлов конфигураций получается по количеству объектов и некрасивой смотрится, что их несколько штук валяется в корне с программой. Хотелось бы, чтобы их было одна штука, где все объекты описаны.

Comment: А Вы объедените их в один класс и файлик получится один

Comment: Наверное я плохо рассказал проблему - создаётся структурированный, полноценный файл xml. С заголовком и корневым узлом. Если я объединю такие два файла (а у меня их пять) то результирующий файл будет некорректной структуры.
Вот только не предлагайте объединять таким образом файлы и перед использованием их опять разбивать...Это быдлокодинг.
Уж лучше я тогда эти файлы помещу в какой-нибудь контейнер, чем буду так их склеивать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

т.к. в коментарий не войдет - пишу сюда.
Если я Вас правильно понял, то у вас есть несколько классов, описывающих конфигурацию разных модулей. Например такие:

```
public class Settings1
{
   ...
}

public class Settings2
{
   ...
}
```

Соответсвтенно сериализуете вы их в разные файлы.

Я же Вам предлагаю сделать так:

```
public class ApplicationSettings
{
   public Settings1 Settings1 {get;set;}
   public Settings1 Settings2 {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

Соответсвенно сериализуем `ApplicationSettings` и получаем 1 файл в котором все что нам надо есть. И для простоты работы `ApplicationSettings` можно сделать Singleton'ом с двумя методами `Load` и `Save`, назначение которых, я думаю, понятны

**--------------------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------------------**

Если список то можно так: делаем общий класс, у Вас интерфейс, но с ним не получится, поэтому сделаем базовый абстрактный класс

```
public abstract SettingsBase
{
  ...
}
```

От него у нас будут наследоваться все наши классы конфигураций:

```
public class Settings1 : SettingsBase
{
   ...
}

public class Settings2 : SettingsBase
{
   ...
}
```

И чтобы сериализатор отработал нам надо классу `SettingsBase` прописать атрибут [XmlInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Таким образом базовый класс будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Settings1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Settings2))]
public abstract SettingsBase
{
   ...
}
```

После этого мы сможем сериализовать такую коллекцию:

```
List<SettingsBase> Settings;
```

Comment: Количество конфигураций не известно, они все разные, но все являются реализацией интерфейса конфигурации. Я не могу их статически объявить в классе обертки. Молу лишь их список сделать... 
Попробую на тестовой программе проверить, но мне кажется, что ничего не получится, нужно будет как-то их разделить. Возможно есть атрибут для указания разделов, вроде видел что-то подобное как и xmlroot, указанное в ответе ниже.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Т.е. при появлении новой конфигурации, мне придётся пересобирать модуль т.к. я должен добавить атрибут к базовому классу? Некрасивое решение....

Comment: > при появлении новой конфигурации

Что Вы под этим подразумеваете? Новая конфигурация же подразумевает класс для ее описания. А как Вы хотите добавить класс, не пересобрав при этом проект?

Comment: @Donil, да, пожалуй, я зря так сильно упростил свою проблему. Сейчас дополню вопрос описанием "проекта" и распределения по модулям.

Comment: @pincher1519, тогда, я думаю, Вам придется писать что-то свое. Можно попробовать наследовать интерфейс `IXmlSerializable` - может что-то и получится.

Answer (score 0):

Все конфигурационные объекты можно хранить в одном файле. Для этого нужно всех их поместить в один класс и сериализовать этот новый класс. Небольшой пример:

```
[XmlRoot("Configuration", Namespace = "")]
public class Configuration
{
    public ConfigObject1 Config1 { get; set; }

    public ConfigObject2 Config2 { get; set; }

    public ConfigObject3 Config2 { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

где `ConfigObjectN` - это ваши нынешние конфигурационные классы.

В итоге, после сериализации такого объекта должен получится XML-файл следущей структуры:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
    <Config1>
        ...
    </Config1>
    <Config2>
        ...
    </Config2>
    <Config3>
        ...
    </Config3>
</Configuration>
```